# Loop 2 per 2 Divs of a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to loop this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy6je/9/), but when I get the last div (in this case the number 6) is shown only the div number 1 and the loop breaks.

The same occurs when I try go back from div 1: Arriving at number 1 is shown the div number 6 and the loop breaks . Would anyone fix this?

This my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="right_curriculum_container">
<img src="img/1_c_left_arrow.png" id="left_arrow" width="26" height="26" alt="Previous" title="Previous">
<div id="new_container">
<div id="image_container">

<div class="center_image">1</div>
<div class="center_image">2</div>

<div class="center_image">3</div>
<div class="center_image">4</div>

<div class="center_image">5</div>
<div class="center_image">6</div>



</div>
</div>
<img src="img/1_c_right_arrow.png" id="right_arrow" width="26" height="26" alt="Next" title="Next"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left_arroq {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;  
}
#right_arrow {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    top:112px;
    left:388px;
}
#left_arrow {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    top:112px;
}
/* Added New_Container */
#new_container {
width: 350px;
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
margin-left:36px;
}
#image_container {
    height: 250px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.center_image {
    height: 235px;
    width: 163px;
    background-color: #606060;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #7ACBBF;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


   var $imgWidth = $('.center_image').first().outerWidth();
   var $imgCount = $('.center_image').length;
   $('#image_container').width($imgWidth*($imgCount+30));
   $('.center_image').first().addClass('the_first');
   $('.center_image').last().addClass('the_last');
   $('.the_first').clone().appendTo('#image_container');


   $('.the_last').clone().prependTo('#image_container');
   $('.center_image').css({'left':-1*$imgWidth-9+'px'}); 


   $('#left_arrow').click(function() {
$('.center_image').stop(true,true);  
      var $newLeft = $('.center_image').position().left+(2*($imgWidth)+16);
      $('.center_image').animate({'left':$newLeft+'px'},function(){
         if (Math.abs($newLeft) == (($imgCount+1)*$imgWidth)) 
            {
            $('.center_image').css({'left':-1*$imgWidth -9+'px'}); 
            }
         });
      return false;
   });

    $('#right_arrow').click(function() {
$('.center_image').stop(true,true); 
      var $newLeft = $('.center_image').position().left-(2*($imgWidth)+16);
      $('.center_image').animate({'left':$newLeft+'px'},function(){
         if (Math.abs($newLeft) == (0)) 
            {
            $('.center_image').css({'left':-($imgCount)*$imgWidth-9+'px'});
            }
    });
   return false;
     });

});
```

Comment: Looks like your code was orginally build to scroll one picture at the time. Therefor at the start of the code to first picture is added to the end, and vice versa. In the callback of the animate it is supposed to move the deck of pictures back/forward so you don't have to create additional elements in the DOM. In your code it looks you have altered it to move two pictures at the time but the code move the complete slide deck isn't updated. I had 10 minutes of looking at it but couldn't figure it out really. Perhaps if you post the original code it would be easier.

Comment: The above code was adapted from this site: [link](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/jquery-endless-slider/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the code you are using was created to display only one image in the viewport a simple solution would be to create a new div that wrapp blocks (2x2) of div center_image, making only 1 div is moved instead of 2.